# jquery each delay without effect

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout, each

I am trying to use the each function and have a pause between the execution of each iteration.  Specifically, I want the script to open a bunch of URLs in new windows, but I want there to be a 2 second pause between each window opening.  Right now each of the links opens without a pause in between.  Below is my code right now.  I don't know how to use the delay() function since I'm not then calling another jQuery effect after the delay.  I've also tried setTimeout to no avail.  What am I missing?

```
    $('.url').each(function() {
        url = $(this).attr("href");
        window.open('http://www.google.com' + url);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the index parameter of the `.each()`[<sup>DOCS</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method in order to multiply your setTimeout delay by the index of the item.  This is because the iterations in the each loop are processed immediately, so you'll essentially be setting delays of 0, 2000, 4000, 6000, etc:

```
$('.url').each(function(i) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open('http://www.google.com' + url);
    }, 2000*i);
});
```

Comment: +1 I liked the style you used for linking to the original documentation for `.each()`. I think I'll steal it :)

Comment: 1. `url` should be a local variable 2. The `elem` parameter is not used, so you don't need to specify it

Comment: @Raynos, gotta be quick!  @Ates, I stole it from jAndy.  @Sime, answer adjusted.

Comment: Thank you to mVChr and everyone else.  4 minutes for a response.  You guys make Stack Overflow awesome!